# How to delete registry key from vc++ coding

Tags: visual-c++, registry

I have a key in registry name **my_software**.

I want to delete it from vc++ coding.[image]

```
CRegKey key;
LPCSTR lpszKey =  "SOFTWARE\\my_software";
key.m_hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
LONG lRes = key.Open(key.m_hKey, lpszKey);
LONG err = key.DeleteSubKey(lpszKey);
```

When I debug the code err has value 0x00000002.
When I saw in winerror.h file it means ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
bool DeleteValueKey(HKEY hKeyRoot, std::string Subkey, std::string ValueKey)
{
    HKEY    hKey        = NULL;
    bool    bReturn     = false;

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, Subkey.c_str(), 0, KEY_SET_VALUE , &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {                   
        if (RegDeleteKey(hKey, ValueKey.c_str() ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            bReturn = true;
        }
    }

    if(hKey != NULL){RegCloseKey(hKey);}

    return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: Usage: DeleteValueKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\my_software","folder");